# Однородные члены, соединенные повторяющимся союзом "и"

Tags: пунктуация

Эти сочетания технологий можно и продолжить, но важно, чтобы потребители поняли, что в сегодняшних условиях российские ученые и производители могут и разрабатывать и выпускать высокоресурсные изделия.

Однородные члены, соединенные повторяющимся союзом "и", разделяются запятой, однако, если эти однородные члены образуют тесное смысловое единство, то запятая не ставится. Например: Были и лето и осень дождливы. Кругом было и светло и зелено. Вопрос: Здесь образуется подобное смысловое единство?

Answer (score 1):

Никак не просматривается здесь тесное смысловое единство, так как слова "разрабатывать" и "выпускать" имеют различное значение, которое невозможно выразить обобщенно, одним словом, как можно сделать применительно к приведенным Вами примерам (и лето и осень=времена года; и светло и зелено= красиво)

Comment: А нельзя ли их заменить глаголом "делать"?

Comment: Думаю, нет, так как "разрабатывать" и "выпускать" обозначают разные этапы  процесса

Answer (score 1):

Смысловое единство однородных членов может следовать из контекста.

Если, к примеру, говорилось о том, что мы обычно можем только разрабатывать продукцию, то "и разрабатывать и выпускать" воспринимается как единое сочетание. Оно произносится без паузы и пишется без запятой.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

Вообще говоря, рассматривать предложение вне текста - значит получить не всегда корректный ответ. Повторяющийся союз И...И не равен одиночному союзу И, у него есть дополнительный оттенок смысла. Он подчеркивает: берем "и то и это", разделения и выбора нет. И такие ситуации возможны не только в художественном тексте.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, это относится главным образом к художественному тексту. А у вас запятая нужна.

Но я бы убрал первое И. *Могут разрабатывать и выпускать*. Ни к чему эта "художественность".

Comment: Согласен с Ниманд, первая запятая ни к чему. Да и ставится она крайне редко.